# amadeus api - this return 404 - any idea why?

Tags: amadeus

curl -X GET "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-dates?origin=LON&destination=NYC&departureDate=2022-10-01&oneWay=true&nonStop=false&viewBy=DATE" -H  "accept: application/vnd.amadeus+json" -H  "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Answer (score 1):

it is under internal analysis. The service will return soon in Test environment.

https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-code-examples/blob/master/flight_cheapest_date_search/v1/get/curl/flight_cheapest_date_search.sh

```
curl -X GET "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-dates?origin=MAD&destination=MUC" -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" -k
{"errors":[{"status":404,"code":6003,"title":"ITEM/DATA NOT FOUND OR DATA NOT EXISTING","detail":"No price result found"},{"status":404,"code":6003,"title":"ITEM/DATA NOT FOUND OR DATA NOT EXISTING","detail":"No price results found for input combined criteria"}]}
```

Comment: Is it still down ? Do you have a status page ?

Comment: Same for ```test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-destinations```. Is there a projection on the availability schedule?

Answer (score 0):

Try /v2/shopping instead of /v1/shopping

The docs are wrong in places, namely the Get Started, confusing numerous developers.